# numba does not compile a function with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

This is my func

```
def _hargreaves_samani_02(r0, im, tmax, tmin, tavg):
    """
    r0 and im are numpy 1D array dtype=int32
    tmax, tmin, tavg are numpy 1D array dtype=float32
    """
    et = np.empty(tmax.size, np.float32)
    for i in range(et.size):
        et[i] = r0[im[i]] * (tmax[i] - tmin[i])**0.5 + 0.0023 * (tavg[i] + 17.78)
    return et
```

I have the following error when I try with @jit(nopython=True) -but no error with @jit(forceobj=True)-

etd = BHIMES._hargreaves_samani_02(sr, months, tmax, tmin, tavg)
File "C:\Users\solis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 351, in _compile_for_args
error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
File "C:\Users\solis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 318, in error_rewrite
reraise(type(e), e, None)
File "C:\Users\solis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py", line 658, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)

numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function() with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float32, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))

parameterized
In definition 0:
All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of setitem at C:\Users\solis\Documents\DEV\python3\Recarga\bhimes\bhimes.py (442)

File "bhimes.py", line 442:
def _hargreaves_samani_02(r0, im, tmax, tmin, tavg):

for i in range(et.size):
et[i] = r0[int(im[i])] * (tmax[i] - tmin[i])**0.5 + 0.0023 * (tavg[i] + 17.78)
^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

List item

Comment: `r0[im[i]]` is probably too complex indexing.

Comment: Try removing the `r0[im]` indexing outside of the loop, or even outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with test data and it was a problem with the arguments I passed to the function; thus this code works ok

```
from numba import jit, float32, int32, void

@jit(void(float32[:], int32[:], float32[:],float32[:],float32[:],float32[:]), python=True)
def hargreaves_samani(r0, im, tmax, tmin, tavg, et):
    for i in range(et.size):
        et[i] = 0.0023 * (tavg[i] + 17.78) + r0[im[i]] * (tmax[i] - tmin[i])**0.5
```